# pipenv not installing external package's dependencies: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pipenv

I have an external package, `mypackage`, hosted at the following (made-up) URL: `https://github.com/someuser/mypackage.git`. That repo has the following Pipfile:

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pandas = "*"
scikit-learn = "*"
xgboost = "*"
numpy = "*"
scipy = "*"
matplotlib = "*"
pycarrot = { git = 'https://github.com/someuser/mypackage.git', editable = true }
```

When I install just `mypackage` with:

```sh
export PIPENV_NOSPIN=1
pipenv install -e git+https://github.com/someuser/mypackage.git@master#egg=mypackage
```

Everything installs just fine. Then I go into the pipenv shell with `pipenv run python3`. I can succesfully `import mypackage`, but when importing another package, e.g. `pandas`, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

It is my assumption the external dependencies for `mypackage` listed above would also be installed when installing `mypackage`. What am I missing here?